# .NET API Core 5 Integration Test 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to create a Integration test project for my .NET core API using NUnit.

I'm getting an exception 404 when I tried API call.

I gave created FakeStartup class for my Testing. It just a copy if my startup.

**Note:- If I passed Startup class for my IntegrationTestFactory, it working fine without issues.**

> private readonly IntegrationTestFactory factory = new();

```
public class IntegrationTestFactory<TTestStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TTestStartup> where TTestStartup : class
    {
        protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<TTestStartup>();
                    webBuilder.UseEnvironment("Development");
                })
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));

            return host;
        }
    }
```

Below is my Test class

```
[TestFixture]
public class SimpleIntegrationTests
{
    private readonly IntegrationTestFactory<FakeStartup> factory = new();

    [Test]
    public async Task SimpleTestCase()
    {
        var client = factory.CreateClient();

        // Arrange
        var faker = new Faker();
        var password = $"{faker.Internet.Password(prefix: "TestPassword12@")}$"; //to satisfy the requirement for passwords

        var mockData = new Faker<SaveUserCommand>()
            .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, f => f.Name.LastName(Name.Gender.Male))
            .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, f => f.Name.LastName(Name.Gender.Male))
            .RuleFor(u => u.EmailAddress, (f, u) => f.Internet.Email(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
            .RuleFor(u => u.MobileNumber, f => f.Phone.PhoneNumberFormat(10))
            .RuleFor(u => u.Password, password)
            .RuleFor(u => u.ConfirmPassword, password)
            .RuleFor(u => u.IsFromRegistrationPage, false)
            .RuleFor(u => u.RoleType, f => f.PickRandom<RoleType>())
            .RuleFor(u => u.PurposeType, f => f.PickRandom<PurposeType>());

        var command = mockData.Generate();

        var stringContent = new StringContent(command.ToJson(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/user", stringContent);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct (haven't written unit tests for API in a long time). Is that you can still add the controller in your test like a normal test so something like this would the test look like. You can use the controller with the type of call you want to do.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SimpleIntegrationTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task SimpleTestCase()
    {
        var controller = new yourControllerName(); //You can add the services it needs above (recommend mocking)
        
        // Arrange
        var faker = new Faker();
        var password = $"{faker.Internet.Password(prefix: "TestPassword12@")}$"; //to satisfy the requirement for passwords

        var mockData = new Faker<SaveUserCommand>()
            .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, f => f.Name.LastName(Name.Gender.Male))
            .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, f => f.Name.LastName(Name.Gender.Male))
            .RuleFor(u => u.EmailAddress, (f, u) => f.Internet.Email(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
            .RuleFor(u => u.MobileNumber, f => f.Phone.PhoneNumberFormat(10))
            .RuleFor(u => u.Password, password)
            .RuleFor(u => u.ConfirmPassword, password)
            .RuleFor(u => u.IsFromRegistrationPage, false)
            .RuleFor(u => u.RoleType, f => f.PickRandom<RoleType>())
            .RuleFor(u => u.PurposeType, f => f.PickRandom<PurposeType>());

        var command = mockData.Generate();

        var stringContent = new StringContent(command.ToJson(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = controller.Post(stringContent);
    }
}
```

Wrote this in notepad don't have a coding program on this laptop. So let me know if it works or if you need more help.

Comment: I would like to test my endpoint using HttpClient. I'm wondering its working as excepted when I pass my Startup instead FakeStartup

Comment: I am not sure about that. Can I ask why you want to test it with HttpClient?